# Image Conversion to Grayscale not working on 32 bit machines

Tags: c#, image-processing, .net-3.5, windows-services, 32bit-64bit

I have a windows service that converts images to black & white and sepia thumbnails. My machine is a 64 bit Windows 7. The server on which I am installing the service is a 32 bit Windows Server 2003.

The code working perfectly on my machine as well as other 64 bit machines but on the server it does not convert images to black & white and sepia.

I have set the Platform target to x86 for my project.

I am using VS 2008 with framework 3.5 and c#.

Following is the code.

```
    private Bitmap ConvertToBlackAndWhite(Bitmap loImage)
    {
        int height = loImage.Height;
        int width = loImage.Width;

        for (int yCoordinate = 0; yCoordinate < height; yCoordinate++)
        {
            for (int xCoordinate = 0; xCoordinate < width; xCoordinate++)
            {
                //Get the pixel that's at our current coordinate.
                Color color = loImage.GetPixel(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

                //Calculate the gray to use for this pixel.
                int grayColor = (int)(color.R * 0.3 + color.G * 0.59 + color.B * 0.11);

                //Set the pixel to the new gray color.
                loImage.SetPixel(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, Color.FromArgb(grayColor, grayColor, grayColor));
            }
        }

        return loImage;
    }
```

I have been trying to google it for quite some time and have not been able to find anything so far.

All help that comes before me going bald is greatly appreciated :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: And there is no exceptions? I believe `Bitmap` class and its get/set pixel methods should work fine on all versions...

Comment: No there are no exceptions.

Comment: I testet your code on 32 bit windows. Worked fine. Perhaps the error is somewhere outside this routine? What do you do with the returned Bitmap?

Comment: I get the thumbnails from the returned image and save them. 
loImage.GetThumbnail function.

Comment: Ok, for test: save the modified bitmap and see if the bitmap is grayscale. The GetThumbnail will return the embedded thumbnail if one is present in the image. That may be the problem. If the Bitmap really is grayscaled, scale the thumbnail yourself.

Comment: When this function returns, i saved the image and it was still a color image rather than a grayscale. However when i get the thumbnail from the processed image, the thumbnail come out to be grayscale. All this is happening on my 64 bit machine. On the 32 bit machine, even the thumbnail remains colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve the issue. If I process the thumbnail rather than the image itself , the issue goes away. Thanks @mh for pointing it out for me.